# Error with yeoman, while trying to install the yo mean js application generator

Tags: node.js, yeoman, bower, mean-stack, meanjs

I am trying to install and work on the MEAN.js stack. I am facing issues while installing the meanjs application generator from yeoman. here is the error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! mean@0.0.1 postinstall: `bower install --config.interactive=false`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mean@0.0.1 postinstall script 'bower install 
--config.interactive=false'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mean package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower install --config.interactive=false
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mean
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
```

npm-debug.log ->

```
90 info postinstall mean@0.0.1
91 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
92 info mean@0.0.1 Failed to exec postinstall script
93 verbose stack Error: mean@0.0.1 postinstall: `bower install --config.interactive=false`
93 verbose stack Exit status 1
93 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
93 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
93 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:14:12)
93 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
93 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
93 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
94 verbose pkgid mean@0.0.1
95 verbose cwd C:\
96 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
97 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
98 error node v0.12.2
99 error npm  v2.7.4
100 error code ELIFECYCLE
101 error mean@0.0.1 postinstall: `bower install --config.interactive=false`
101 error Exit status 1
102 error Failed at the mean@0.0.1 postinstall script 'bower install --config.interactive=false'.
102 error This is most likely a problem with the mean package,
102 error not with npm itself.
102 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
102 error     bower install --config.interactive=false
102 error You can get their info via:
102 error     npm owner ls mean
102 error There is likely additional logging output above.
103 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Unable to find help online.

I am working on a windows 8.1 64 bit env. Some pointers please.

Comment: It looks like the `bower install` step is failing. You could try re-running it yourself to get more details on the error. I'd also be curious to see what's in `npm-debug.log` :)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. yeah tried installing bower that works independently but yo meanjs throws this error. let me add the npm log.

Comment: If `bower install` worked independently and there were no other errors you might be good to go. Fire up the project and see if its working. And of course feel free to post logs here if you want to solve the yo mystery.

Comment: sorry for the trouble will use code formatting the next time. I was able to run the project however its just a blank page. I guess some steps in the post install need to be run after the error with bower. :(